# Google Cloud Storage Multi-Regional bucket slow deletion

Tags: google-cloud-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am experiencing slow deletion for a GCS Multi-Regional bucket.
I was wondering if this is normal performance to be expected since the bucket is Multi-Regional.

My bucket is being deleted programmatically by Terraform, and the delete step has taken 16 minutes:
`google_storage_bucket.<REDACTED>: Still destroying... (ID: <REDACTED>, 16m30s elapsed)`

When i go into the GCS console, when I check (click, select) the bucket, and click Delete, it takes a long time while a tooltip appears saying "Checking the bucket".
After that it asks me if I want to delete the X number of items.
After I choose yes, it tells me it failed.

When I first did the delete step in GCS console, it said 146 items.
I repeated it again later and it says 102 items, which probably means 40 items were deleted.

How can I delete this bucket properly?
Is this performance expected, since it is multi-regional?

UPDATE:
**33 minutes** and it is still deleting (as per Terraform)

**UPDATE:**
Deletion is complete
`google_storage_bucket.vault: Destruction complete after 52m48s`
So I don't need a fix, but it'll be nice to know if this is normal expected performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior, when a bucket is going to be deleted, all objects are recursively listed to know if they are all deleted. Usually this is pretty quick, but it can take a very long time if there are a lot of objects.

As a workaround you can [delete the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm) faster running `gsutil rm -m -r gs://bucket`
to perform parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) removes.

Also there is an [already filed feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35901840) for this issue, you can click on the `Me too!` button to indicate that you are affected by this issue.

Comment: The parallelism modifier is to be applied on `gsutil` rather than rm .. the working command is `gsutil -m rm -r gs://bucket`